# architecture for REST service layer

Tags: web-services, rest, architecture, soap

I want to build a service layer which consumes a lot of SOAP and XML/HTTP web services and makes them all available through REST. How would one go about developing the architecture of this new layer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
10 MAKE THE NOUNS OF YOUR SYSTEM INTO RESTFUL RESOURCES IDENTIFIED BY URIS
20 DEFINE MEDIA TYPES AND LINKS BETWEEN RESOURCES
30 IMPLEMENT RESTFUL DESIGN USING STUBBED-OUT METHODS
40 IF WRITING A CLIENT OF YOUR REST API SUCKS THEN GOTO 10
50 CHOOSE A SOAP TOOLKIT
60 IMPLEMENT SOAP DELEGATION CODE WITHIN YOUR REST API
70 IF SOAP TOOLKIT CHOICE DRIVES YOU INSANE THEN GOTO 50
80 DEPLOY IT
90 OK I CAN NO LONGER RESIST IT, HERE IT COMES
100 PRINT I AM KOOL
110 GOTO 100
```

Comment: any SOAP toolkit recommendations?

Comment: Sure, Apache CXF if you're using Java.